# border and box-shadow issues with table-cell elements in IE 9/10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, css

I am using CSS `display: table-cell` to display a bunch of **LI** elements next to each other. Those are abundantly styled, having an intended appearance like this:

[image: As intended]

However, in IE 9 and 10, it is rendered like this:

[image: IE9+10]

I was unable to figure out what is wrong here, but when i experimentally set the **LI**-Elements to `display: block` the elements suddenly rendered fine.

Here is the CSS:

```
display:            table-cell;
height:             27px;
line-height:        26px;
text-align:         center;
box-shadow:         inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-ms-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-o-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
background: #ededed; /* Old browsers */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%,#ededed), color-stop(100%,#dfdfdf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%,#dfdfdf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%,#dfdfdf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%,#dfdfdf 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ededed 5%,#dfdfdf 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
border:             1px solid #b7b7b7;
border-right:       0;
text-decoration:    none;
cursor:             pointer;
```

Finally i discovered some articles on a seemingly similar issue with the solution being presented as using:

border-collapse: separate;

on the element. However, if i do this, i get the following results in IE:

[image: IE after modification]

So obviously the top-border gets rendered. But not any other styles as it seems.

What is wrong here and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing i finally found the source of the problem:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

After removing this, IE started to render everything fine right away. If anyone knows why the appliance of the filter causes such a problem, please share your wisdom. Thank You!